# TStringList is not passing value

Tags: delphi, procedure, tstringlist

So i have a procedure, that is getting the list of dom nodes.

```
procedure TmainForm.getNodeListByClass(className:string; outputList:TStringList);
var
  foundNode:TDomTreeNode;
  foundNodesList:TStringlist;
begin
foundNodesList:=Tstringlist.Create;

foundNode:=nodeFindNodeByClassName(DomTree.RootNode,className);
if Assigned(foundNode) then
    getNodeList(foundNode,foundNodesList);

outputList:=foundNodesList;
freeandnil(foundNodesList);
end;
```

And a procedure that is using it

```
procedure TmainForm.getByXpathBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  temp:TStringlist;

begin
temp:=TStringlist.Create;

temp.Add('testval');

getNodeListByClass('table_input',temp);
memo1.Lines:=temp;

getNodeListByClass('left iteminfo',temp);
dbgForm.memo1.Lines:=temp;

getNodeListByClass('left',temp);
dbgForm.memo2.Lines:=temp;

freeandnil(temp);
end;
```

And i really don't understand, why it wouldn't work, result of first procedure is always empty.
I found out, that when the first procedure is executing, "foundNodesList" have the correct list, and setting it to "outputList" is working too, but as soon as its returning to the second procedure (in "temp" list) its just empty. 
So its clearing old data from "test" ('testval' what i am writing in the beginning), but not adding the result from the first one.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
outputList := foundNodesList;
FreeAndNil(foundNodesList);
```

The assignment is a reference assignment. I think that you are expecting the content of `foundNodesList` to be transferred into `outputList`. But what happens is that you end up with two variables referring to the same instance.

Your code can be fixed very easily. You do not need a temporary string list, you can simply populate the string list passed into the method.

```
procedure TmainForm.getNodeListByClass(className: string; outputList: TStringList);
var
  foundNode: TDomTreeNode;
begin
  outputList.Clear;
  foundNode := nodeFindNodeByClassName(DomTree.RootNode, className);
  if Assigned(foundNode) then
    getNodeList(foundNode, outputList);
end;
```

Note that in the other function when you write

```
memo1.Lines := temp;
```

this works a little differently. The `Lines` property of a `TMemo` has a property setter that **copies** the right hand side, rather than taking a reference. Your code that performs assignment to `Lines` is therefore correct.

Comment: I tested it, works like a charm! I thought that since values are already passed to `outputList` i could destroy `foundNodesList`, didn't know, that its just a reference. Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the problem is not only the freeing: the caller will never see the new value of `outputList` anyway, since it is not a `var` parameter. Still, +1, of course! :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You are right. Your answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

You must understand that objects are *reference types* in Delphi, and that these references are passed by value. So your procedure

```
procedure TmainForm.getNodeListByClass(className:string; outputList:TStringList);
var
  foundNode:TDomTreeNode;
  foundNodesList:TStringlist;
begin
foundNodesList:=Tstringlist.Create;

foundNode:=nodeFindNodeByClassName(DomTree.RootNode,className);
if Assigned(foundNode) then
    getNodeList(foundNode,foundNodesList);

outputList:=foundNodesList;
freeandnil(foundNodesList);
end;
```

will never change the `outputList` of the caller. Indeed, the line

```
outputList:=foundNodesList;
```

merely sets the `getNodeListByClass` procedure's *own local variable* `outputList`, which was only a copy of the pointer to the caller's string list. Hence, this copy of the pointer is changed, but the actual object, and the caller's pointer to it, are left unchanged.

Also, even if this had not been the case, your code would have had a bug, because

```
freeandnil(foundNodesList);
```

destroys the string list object `foundNodesList`, and this is the same object that `outputList` points to at that point. Hence, if the caller would have been able to see the "new" `outputList` (if it had been a `var` parameter), it would only see a dangling pointer (memory corruption bug).

What you need is

```
procedure TmainForm.getNodeListByClass(const className: string; outputList: TStringList);
var
  foundNode: TDomTreeNode;
  foundNodesList: TStringlist;
begin
  foundNodesList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    foundNode := nodeFindNodeByClassName(DomTree.RootNode, className);
    if Assigned(foundNode) then
      getNodeList(foundNode, foundNodesList);  
    outputList.Assign(foundNodeList);
  finally
    foundNodeList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

assuming your functions do what I think they do. But this can be simplified to

```
procedure TmainForm.getNodeListByClass(const className: string; outputList: TStringList);
var
  foundNode: TDomTreeNode;
begin
  outputList.Clear;
  foundNode := nodeFindNodeByClassName(DomTree.RootNode, className);
  if Assigned(foundNode) then
    getNodeList(foundNode, outputList);  
end;
```

(I don't know if you want to append the list or replace it. You have to adjust the code accordingly.)

Also, notice that you always must protect your objects, using `try..finally` blocks, for instance. Your code must never leak resources (memory, for instance), not even if an exception is raised!

Comment: Pointless to make a new string list instance, may as well use the one that is provided

Comment: @David: Indeed, I just made a new comment about that. I still want to keep the intermediate step for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: You'd need to clear `outputList` also, in case no node was found, for instance

Comment: Got it. That stringlist was just a leftover from the place i extracted this procedure from. But why use free instead of freeandnil?

Comment: @A.Daty: `FreeAndNil` will also work here, but it is unnecessary. The only difference is that `FreeAndNil` also sets the pointer to `nil` (to avoid having a dangling pointer), but in this case, the pointer variable is `foundNodeList`, which is a local variable that goes out of scope in only two lines of code, so it is obvious that no one will see its value anyway. Still, in other cases, `FreeAndNil` is a good practice. You often *need* that when you deal with variables that live longer and that vary between `nil` and non-`nil` states.